# Can't RDP to Azure Virtual Machine (Ubuntu 16.04LTS)

Tags: ubuntu, remote-desktop, azure

I've setup an Azure virtual machine using **Ubuntu 16.04LTS** but I'm struggling to get remote desktop to work for it.

I've setup the endpoint as follows:

[image]

I've also setup and started `xrdp` as well as installed `xfce4`. For reference, here's my command history since creating the VM:

**Update Packages and Install xfce4**

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install xfce4
```

**Install xrdp**

```
sudo apt-get install xrdp

sudo /etc/init.d/xrdp start
```

**Create new user and add to sudo group**

```
sudo adduser rdpuser

sudo adduser rdpuser sudo
```

Even after having done this I can still only SSH to my Virtual Machine. The RDP client is timing out with the following:

[image]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have your source port locked at 3389. This should be set to `*`, as it represents traffic origination port.

Your other settings look fine.

Comment: Thanks! I've updated this and also found that checkpoint was blocking my outgoing connection (registering it as the NoMachine client). Will accept as the answer since it looks like  this wasn't working due to multiple things at play.